# How to refresh another page using javascript (without opening the same page in a new tab) both the pages are Under the same Domain and in 1 script

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload, page-refresh

So i want to send data form the first page using localStorge method in js
and when the localStorge have data in them (not equals to null)
i want the second page to be refreshed so i can display the data in the second page

i tried this to refresh  the second page each 4s

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(1);
}, 4000);
```

it does work but i have to wait until the images are display and all
and i am afraid the second i published the site it crashes of to many refreshes

Q1: is it bad to refresh the page so many times ?Does the website crashes?
Q2:is there any way i can refresh the page 2 when the localStorge method is not null ?

Comment: Websockets can be useful. But you need a WS server to broadcast something so into your page you have listeners which will handle this payload provided by ws such as Instructions to reload pages or other stuffs like fill pages with text, sounds familiar? Chats has this principle so instead show text, reload page.

Comment: I have no posted as a answer because there are a lot of approaches applicable

Comment: You can use Window.postMessage() if you have opened 2nd page in popup.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: About reload page every developer must have repulse of. You have ever and forever preserve your server how less requests need better.